# Allocate Object member variable to another double strong pointer

Tags: objective-c, variables, object

We can use a __strong double point like this in Objective-C.

```
NSString *__strong * tmp_pointer;
NSString * target = @"first data";
tmp_pointer = target;
*tmp_pointer = @"second data";
NSLog(@"%@", target);

Output : first data
```

But what about Object variable?

Example : DataObject has a NSString* type variable 'item1'.

```
DataObject *dataObject = [[DataObject alloc] init];
NSString *__strong * tmp_pointer;
tmp_pointer = &dataObject.item1; <- Address of property expression requested error occurred.
```

I tried several expression but everything was failed.

```
tmp_pointer = &(dataObject.item1);
tmp_pointer = &(NSString *)dataObject.item1;
tmp_pointer = &((NSString *)dataObject.item1);
```

Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that a call to a property is really a method call to the getter method. So it makes no sense to get the address of a property.

Comment: YEAH, I'm so stupid that I know the property is just a Getter&Setter all the time, but I just forgot it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a property through dot notation is syntax sugar for a method call, so what you are really doing is

```
&[dataObject item1]
```

which is not allowed by the grammar.

The argument of the `&` is an expression that must be an *lvalue* or a *function designator*  <sup>[1]</sup>, and a method call is neither.

If want the address of the value returned by the getter, you have to turn it into a *lvalue* first. The most straightforward way is to assign it to a local variable:

```
NSString * item1 = dataObject.item1;        // now item1 is a lvalue
NSString * __strong * tmp_pointer = &item1; // so it can be the argument of &
```

---

<sub>[1]</sub>
 <sub>A *function designator* as an expression that has function type.</sub> 
 <sub>An *object* is a region of storage that can be examined and stored into and an *lvalue* is an expression that refers to such an object.</sub> 
<sub>([source](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/lvalue.htm))</sub>

Comment: A clarification for the OP: now tmp_pointer doesn't point to the variable stored in the object, it's a copy of it and if you set it's value (e.g.: *tmp_pointer= @"Hello"), you don't affect the object property.

Comment: Let `P` and `P1` be pointers and `O` be an object. Then given `P1 -> P -> O`, I don't see why dereferencing `P1` I wouldn't get the original `P` back.

Comment: or in other words, if the getter is implemented like `{ return _item1 }`, you are actually passing around a pointer to a `NSString`. By doing `*tmp_pointer` you are getting `_item1` back, so `*tmp_pointer = @"Hello"` will change `item1` to point to `@"Hello"`.

Comment: I'm saying that this assignment changes the value of item1 to @"Hello", but that the pointer stored inside the object isn't affected by this assignment (which seems to be the goal of using a pointer to pointer).

Comment: Oh ok, yep it makes sense now.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri says exactly what I want. Now I realize my expression about property was wrong but the point is 'How can I change original object with the double pointer.'

Comment: @kkds This violated encapsulation and in most cases it's better if you don't do it, use the setter method instead. If you still need to do it, create a getter that returns that pointer to pointer. At this point you should pay attention: the pointer could change at every moment, changed by another object and maybe in another thread, without that you get notified.